# JPA Named Query Returning Empty Array when it Shouldn't

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, named-query

I am trying to query the last 5 digits of a number field from an Oracle DB within a Springboot/JPA Repository.

In Oracle, the following query works:
`Select * FROM DP1_Attachments Where trim(substr(dp1_submit_date_dp1_number, -5, 5)) = [a-five-digit-number]`

I have tried implementing the following:

ENTITY:

```
@IdClass(CompositeKey.class)
public class DP1Attachments {

    @Id
    private  Integer attachmentsFolder;
    @Id
    private  Integer attachmentNumber;

    private  Integer dp1SubmitDateDp1Number;
    private  String attachmentName;
    private  Integer attachmentSize;
    private  String attachmentType;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime attachmentDate;
    private  String attachmentBy;
    private  Integer attachmentByUsersId;
    private  String attachmentActive;
    private  String modifiedBy;
    private  Integer modifiedByUsersId;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
    private  LocalDateTime modifiedDate;
```

REPOSITORY

```
    @Query("SELECT a FROM DP1Attachments a WHERE trim(substring(a.dp1SubmitDateDp1Number, -5, 5)) = :dp1Number")
    List<DP1Attachments> queryByDp1SubmitDateDp1Number(@Param("dp1Number") String dp1Number);

}
```

SERVICE

```
public List<DP1Attachments> getAttachmentsList (String dp1Number){
        return attachmentsRepository.queryByDp1SubmitDateDp1Number(dp1Number);
    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAttachmentsInFolder (@PathVariable String attachmentFolder){
        List<DP1Attachments>files = attachmentsService.getAttachmentsList(attachmentFolder);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(files, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The query runs but returns an empty array.

I also tried changing the substring to a LIKE statement:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM DP1Attachments a WHERE TO_CHAR(a.dp1SubmitDateDp1Number) like :dp1Number")
    List<DP1Attachments> queryByDp1SubmitDateDp1Number(@Param("dp1Number") String dp1Number);
```

And the service changed to :

```
 public List<DP1Attachments> getAttachmentsList (String dp1Number){
        return attachmentsRepository.queryByDp1SubmitDateDp1Number("%" + dp1Number);
    }
```

This also runs w/o errors but returns an empty array.

Comment: didn't run your example, so this is only a guess: I see that `a.dp1SubmitDateDp1Number` is an `Integer` - you might want to try to cast it to a `String` in your query. If everything else fails, you can always use `nativeQuery=true` and use your oracle query in the annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found it was a combination of a few things. First, the default naming schema didn't like the number if the middle of the attribute name so I added @Column(name = "name-in DB") and to what you've pointed out I changed all input types to Strings. Both those together did the trick. Thanks!